# What are the applications, where different multi-label classification performance evaluation metrics should be used?

Tags: classification, multilabel

There are numerous multi-label classification performance evaluation metrics, namely hamming loss, accuracy (or Jaccard-index), subset accuracy (or exact match), example-based (precision, recall, f1-score), micro (precision, recall, f1-score), macro (precision, recall, f1-score), coverage, one-error, average-precision, AUC, ranking loss. I wish to know the different applications of multi-label classification, where these different performance evaluation metrics should be used.

I searched a lot; however, unable to find an article that mentioned one-to-one correspondence between performance evaluation metrics and applications of multi-label classification, i.e., ranking loss is ideal for recommendation system (this is just an example).

Comment: Welcome to this site! This is a rather vague question, and you should probably add more details about the application you have in mind in order to get relevant responses.

Comment: Agreed --  the metric you want to use will be 1) dependent on your specific task, and 2) dependent on the argument you're trying to make with your results.